# iScroll4 height is wrong after ajax form submission. Height is orginal height before form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, iscroll4

I've embedded a form into my iScroll4 scroller. The form is an ajax form, generated by wordpress Gravity forms plugin.

When I hit submit on the form, the height of iscroll (generated on page load) stays the same, which means if the form is bigger after the submit button is pressed, you can't scroll all the way down.

See my code below...

```
var myScroll,
    myScrollSidebar;

function loaded() {
    myScroll            = new iScroll('wrapper');
    myScrollSidebar     = new iScroll('sidebar-wrapper');
}

var formInputs = [
  document.getElementById('gform_submit_button_1'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_1'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_2'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_3'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_4'),
  document.getElementById('input_input_1_5')
];

for(var i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
  formInputs[i].addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
}

jQuery(document).bind('gform_page_loaded', function(){

    var formInputs = [
      document.getElementById('gform_submit_button_1'),
      document.getElementById('input_1_1'),
      document.getElementById('input_1_2'),
      document.getElementById('input_1_3'),
      document.getElementById('input_1_4'),
      document.getElementById('input_input_1_5')
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
      formInputs[i].addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }, false);
    }

});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
```

Can anyone please help me fix it so when the form submits, iScroll's height refreshes perhaps?

The binded jquery is so the form inputs work after the form has be submitted. This is because iscroll4 struggles with form elements.

Thanks in advance.

Josh

Comment: Have you tried recalculation the height of the form after submit and then calling the `refresh` method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make iScroll compute the new height by using myScroll.refresh() (AFTER your AJAX).

This is from the developer's page (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4):

> iScroll needs to know the correct dimensions of both the wrapper and the scroller. They are computed the first time at start up but if your code changes the elements size, iScroll needs to be warned that you are messing with the DOM.
>
> This is achieved by calling the refresh function with the right timing. Please follow me closely, understanding this will save you hours of scrolling frustration.
>
> Every time you change elements height/width or you modify the html structure in any way (eg: appendChild or innerHTML) the browser renderer updates the page. Once the browser applied the changes you can access the new DOM (and properties) from javascript again. Sometimes this process is not instant.